# MySQL - Write to a distinct server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a master slave replication where the application on the slave server needs to write to the master from time to time. When this happens, the writing is slow as the two servers are on different continents.

What is really slow is establishing the connection. Would it be possible to have a unique MySQL connection between the PHP project and the Master MySQL server and which will always be ready to write in the Master DB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Not likely, and you're probably barking up the wrong tree by trying to keep a connection open with php.

You need to look further in to why the connection is so slow. Do more measuring and testing. How much up/downstream bandwidth do you have? Is it being saturated? What about CPU power? Is there encryption happening? Is the handshake taking a long time? If so, try setting up a vpn so the encryption is already taken care of.

Comment: Hi Dale, the reason of the slowness is the fact that the master server is in Europe and the Slave server in China. The connection between the two data centers is really slow. So, it is not possible to speed up the MySQL connection, but I need to see how to keep this connection open and use it for writes.

Comment: Is this of any help?
http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: This may help, but I am using an Nginx server with fastcgi_pass, so I guess I am it this situation: `The first method is to use PHP as a CGI "wrapper". When run this way, an instance of the PHP interpreter is created and destroyed for every page request (for a PHP page) to your web server. Because it is destroyed after every request, any resources that it acquires (such as a link to an SQL database server) are closed when it is destroyed. In this case, you do not gain anything from trying to use persistent connections -- they simply don't persist.`